# classes.jar issue in HelloWorld : Eclipse on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, ide

When I run this `HelloWorld.java` program below

```
public class HelloWorld {

     public static void main (String [] args) {


        System.out.println("Hello World");


    }   


}
```

after installing the latest version of Eclipse on my Mac OS 10.7.2, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Upon clicking on the URLClassLoader exception i see this:

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0.jdk/Content/Classes/classes.jar has no source attachment
```

This is a super basic program I'm trying to run and i'm having these issues with the mac...all help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I have a feeling that this caused by your OSX Lion. JDK 1.6.0 is not compatible with Lion. Read http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1421. You can also try springsource. their build usually more stabil in mac. http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts

Comment: Is this Eclipse Indigo? Also, open up `/Application/Utilities/Java Preferences` and edit your question to include the versions of Java installed on your system.

Comment: are you running the right file? I get that error when playing around with libaries but your code works in the first place. Right beside the run button there's an arrow that you can use to select which project your running.

Answer (score 2):

This worked: Editing the buildpath for the project to use the default Mac OSX java runtime environment. Eclipse was previously pointing specifically to the java 1.6 sdk. I did not have to download and install anything.